# How to run javascript class on php script on a wordpress website?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I am developing a website using Wordpress and I encounter a problem in the call of the javascript file that contains code that allows me to describe animations according to certain events.

Indeed this file contains functions that are called correctly according to certain events. However this file contains a class and this is where I encounter a problem because I can not access the constuctor of this class and its methods.

here is the template which is a .php file:

```
<?php

        if(get_field('test'))
        { ?>
       
        <section>

            <div class="overflow-h" id="parallaxContainer">
                <?php if ( wp_is_mobile() ) {?>
                    <img class="full-img">
                <?php } else { ?>
                    <img class="full-img" data-parallax="0.2" ?> id="target">
                <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </section>
       
    <?php
        }
    ?>
```

here is the javascript file (mains.js):

```
const scrollContainer = document.querySelector("main");

let isDown = false;
let startX;
let scrollLeft;

scrollContainer.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
    isDown = true;
    startX = e.pageX - scrollContainer.offsetLeft;
    scrollLeft = scrollContainer.scrollLeft;
});

scrollContainer.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    isDown = false;
});

scrollContainer.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
    isDown = false;
});

scrollContainer.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    if(!isDown) return;
    e.preventDefault();
    const x = e.pageX - scrollContainer.offsetLeft;
    const walk = (x - startX)/10;
    scrollContainer.scrollLeft = scrollLeft - walk;
});

//Can't access to the class...
class Parallax {
    constructor(element) {
        this.element = element;
        this.onScroll = this.onScroll.bind(this);
        document.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll)
    }

 
 onScroll() {
    const middleScreenWidth = window.scrollX + window.innerWidth / 2;
}


 bind() {
    return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("[data-parallax]")).map(
        (element) => {
            return new Parallax(element);
        });
    }
}
```

this is the .php file that calls the javascript file (main.js): I call my js script thanks to the Wordpress function 'add_action'

```
function call_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'call-style', get_stylesheet_uri(), array(), _S_VERSION );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'call-main', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/main.js', array(), _S_VERSION, true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'call_scripts' );
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Where are you using the `Parallax` class?

Comment: I want to use this class in the above template which contains an image. this image has an attribute "data-parallax". The bind() method that targets each element with this attribute is called in the class constructor. For each element with this attribute, I apply a parallax effect in the constructor using the bind() method. Class code is incomplete at this time.

Comment: Is this on a multisite? Just wondering if `main.js` is even enqueued since you are using `get_stylesheet_uri()` for the styles and `get_template_directory_uri()` for the script file.

Comment: @Olivier I actually meant, where are you calling the first `new Parallax()`? You'll to manually call the `bind` method somewhere for the event listener to be added. FYI, the `scroll` event listener is a very performance heavy event. I'd consider using only 1 scroll event listener for all of your elements. And maybe the `bind` method should be static, as it is kind of odd for a class to be able to create multiple instances of itself.

Comment: @Emiel Zuurbier I’m sorry I didn’t understand your remark... I start in javascript, but I assume that the bind method creates an instance of the Parallax class every time it is called in the constructor. The bind method creates an instance for each element that has the attribute 'data-parallax'. Hope I understood your question. Thank you for your comments about how cumbersome it is. I make this site for a friend who wants a lot of events to scroller (wheel and click and drag on an horizontal scroll on desktop and tablet).

Comment: That's alright. Well, that would be the case if you'd call `this.bind()` from the `constructor`, but don't do that as you would get an inifinite loop and crash your page. I'll post an answer, soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the `bind` logic out of the `class` and put in a seperate function. The reason for this is that you don't want a `Parallax` instance to be able to create more instances as that is not their concern.

```
class Parallax {
  constructor(element) {
    this.element = element;
    document.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll)
  }

  onScroll = () => {
    const middleScreenWidth = window.scrollX + window.innerWidth / 2;
  }
}
```

Create a new function that returns an array of `Parallax` instances. This is [factory function pattern](https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-factory-functions/), which can help in creating multiple instances.

```
function createParallax() {
  return Array.from(document.querySelectorAll("[data-parallax]")).map(
    (element) => new Parallax(element)
  );
}
```

Call the function and store the `Parallax` instances in a variable.

```
const parallaxes = createParallax();
```

Like mentioned earlier: the `scroll` event listener puts a strain on your performance as it is being called with every pixel. If you have to do that, for let's say 10 elements, then it has to do a new calculation 10 times every pixel. This becomes slow very fast.

The solution for this would be to use a single `scroll` event listener, make the event handler a [passive event listener](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/lighthouse/best-practices/uses-passive-event-listeners/), and keep track of the elements that are in view, elements outside of view don't have to be animated, which saves performance.

Comment: Thank you very much for that very comprehensive answer and for your time. I’m going to reflect on the problem.